# Will normal programs know the cgroups memory limitations?

Tags: c++, docker, memory, cgroups, apache-traffic-server

I have a normal program (written in c++) compiled with `make` that I'm running in docker with the `--memory` option.

According to docker stats the memory slowly goes up until it hits the limit I've chosen and then it just flats out. It doesn't get OOMKilled as I would  have guessed.

Is there some version of malloc that notices that the cgroup is out of memory and starts using memory more efficiently (like defrag)?

Or is there any other kind of magic going on here?

The program is Apache Traffic Server and the version is 7.1.x ([source](https://github.com/apache/trafficserver/tree/7.1.x))

Comment: Perhaps it's Apache Traffic Server that "starts using memory more efficiently" when  `new` `throws`/`return`s 0.